# How to reconcile the instruction pointer and the current line in GDB?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, bootloader

I have two code segments: .multiboot.text and .text
They are located in memory as follows:
**linker.ld**

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x00100000;
    /* The kernel will live at 3GB + 1MB in the virtual address space, */
    /* which will be mapped to 1MB in the physical address space. */

    _kernel_start = .;
    .multiboot.text : {
        *(.multiboot.text)
    }

    . += 0xC0000000;
    /* Add a symbol that indicates the start address of the kernel. */
    .text ALIGN (4K) : AT (ADDR (.text) - 0xC0000000)
    {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

**start.asm**

```
section .multiboot.text
. . .
    ; Jump to higher half with an absolute jump.
    ; <breakpoint is successfully triggered here>
    ; <single>
    lea ecx, .higher_half
    jmp ecx

section .text
.higher_half:
    ; Unmap the identity mapping as it is now unnecessary.
    ; <breakpoint doesn't work here>
    mov [boot_page_directory + 0], DWORD 0

    ; Reload crc3 to force a TLB flush so the changes to take effect.
    mov ecx, cr3
    mov cr3, ecx
. . .
```

In my *start.asm* file, I pass control from the *.multiboot.text* segment to the *.text* and IP changes from 0x001????? on 0xC01????? and the debugger cannot reconcile this change with the current line
As a result of this, step-by-step debugging does not work for me
[image: debugging works, but does not display the line]

How can I help him with this?

I compile *start.asm* using nasm and the *-g* flag, which means debugging information is present
Pay attention to the fact that the code itself is physically located in the lower half of memory, however, such a difference in IP is due to virtual memory

Comment: Does it break single-step debugging using `stepi` (alias `si`)?  Or only source-level `step`?  If even asm-level debugging fails, you might want to use Bochs with its built-in debugger which is designed around x86 (and can even handle non-flat segmentation which is apparently useful in early boot before switching to protected mode if writing your own legacy BIOS bootloader, instead of multiboot).

Comment: @PeterCordes, The `step` and `stepi` commands work, but `step` does not displaying the current line (within the same file, it shows the remaining lines in other files correctly) after jumping to the upper half.
I added a screenshot to the text of the question, please look at it.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So `layout asm` / `layout reg` would probably work in stand-alone text-mode GDB, since that's based on disassembly, not source.  (Often a good idea to use that when debugging, in case of accidental overwrites of code or other possible bugs.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, Yes, it seems to be working, thank you!